# Problems manipulating FragmentTransaction backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I have several fragments using the v4 support library. I'm now trying to use the backstack but the FragmentTransaction class appears to be missing all the backstack methods. For example:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager( ).beginTransaction( );
transaction.setCustomAnimations( R.animator.enter, R.animator.leave, R.animator.enter, R.animator.leave );
<other stuff>
transaction.popBackStackImmediate( "fragment_1", 1 );
```

gives the error messsage

```
The method popBackStackImmediate(String, int) is undefined for the type FragmentTransaction
```

Even the `FragmentTransaction.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE` constant is not defined.

BTW: I have installed the file android-support-v13.jar according to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html. I've also tried the android-support-v4.jar and got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html), not [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html). `FragmentManager` has the `popBackStackImmediate` method as well as the constant you mention.